# iOS checking if JSON return has Key

Tags: ios, crash, nsjsonserialization

I'm using NSJsonSerialization to get back a json return after I POST something. I either get back my correct return or I get:

```
{
"status":"false"
}
```

I need to check if I got back my return before I try to parse it (since it crashes if the Keys I ask for don't exist) However if I check against

```
[whatever objectForKey:@"status"] == nil
```

When it is nil it's ok, however if it does not exist it crashes (because I got back my other return)

The crash I get is this one, it seems NSJSONSerialzation is returning a NSArray as a NSdictionary?:

```
2012-07-02 11:03:40.426 [9412:10703] -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75f03f0
2012-07-02 11:03:40.429 [9412:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75f03f0'
```

I need to figure out a way to know which return I got so I can act accordingly.

Comment: What you got back is an array, did the JSON structure change?  You should make sure the instance is an NSDictitonary and not an NSArray before you try to use methods from the NSDictionary class.

Comment: I can't seem to find it now but I do remember that NSJsonSerialization decides to give either a NSDictionary or a NSArray depending on the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could check the type of `whatever` variable

```
if([whatever isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    //then check for nil
else
    //Then its not a dictionary then in your case its empty
```

Comment: Thanks! I check if it's an array (I got back the return) or dictionary (error) I wish Apple had included some type of callback letting you know what it was returning as part of NSJsonSerialization.